# Grails - JSON param request not passing to controller

Tags: json, grails, parameters

I would like to pass a JSON to my requete.
But not possible to find the JSON.

```
@Secured(['ROLE_STUDENT'])
def validate() {
    println params
    println request.JSON
}
```

Result :

```
[controller:student, action:validate, id:2345444]
[:]
```

URL :

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"studentScores":[{"id":"2","score":"17"}],"comment":"good"}' 'http://localhost:8080/myapp/studient/2345444/validate' -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=3CCDC701553A2208428BB7135DDA5546'
```

I tried with GET and POST, and with à JQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlSubmit,
    type: 'POST', 
    data: JSON.stringify(student),
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Grails 2.4.4
Java 8 (compliance level java 7)
Tomcat 8

Some plugins :
spring-security-core:2.0-RC4
spring-security-facebook:0.16.2
spring-security-oauth2-provider:2.0-RC2

Need your help

Comment: the problem is I have a domain class as param of my method : def validate(Student s) { }. It's stange, but with this, request.JSON become empty. To fixe it, I remove the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html (**9.3 GET**).

> The GET method means retrieve whatever information (in the form of an entity) is identified by the Request-URI

Request-URI being the important part here. There is no concept of body data in a GET requests.

So, change to POST and your request should work.

Comment: I tried GET beacause POST not works, but both have same effect -> not works

Comment: With GET will not work. I just create an application and made the request with [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm), I received the json perfectly. Maybe the problem is in another place. Have you made any changes in urlMappings for example?

Comment: I'm not familiar with curl, maybe there is a problem in your curl request

Answer (score 0):

For first u have an error in your url in curl :)

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/STUDIENT/2345444/validate
```

try this code

```
def json = JSON.stringify(params)
```

but I don't sure.